# Аннотация метода класса enum в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enum, аннотации

У меня есть класс `FigureNames(enum.Enum)`. Как в аннотации указать, что `classmethod` возвращает результат `FigureNames.name`?

```
class FigureNames(enum.Enum):

    rectangle = "Прямоугольник"
    parallelogram = "Параллелограмм"
    square = "Квадрат"
    rhombus = "Ромб"
    trapezium1 = "Трапеция равнобедренная"
    trapezium2 = "Трапеция прямоугольная"
    triangle = "Треугольник"
    hexagon = "Шестиугольник"
    circle = "Окружность"
    prism = "Призма"
    cuboid = "Параллелепипед"
    cube = "Куб"
    pyramid = "Пирамида"
    cylinder = "Цилиндр круговой"
    cone = "Конус круговой"
    sphere = "Шар, сфера"

    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def keyForValue(cls, figure: str) -> "FigureNames":  # ??
        data = tuple(cls)
        for object_ in data:
            if object_.value == figure:
                return object_
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class  Смотрели?

Comment: Если метод возвращает `FigureNames.name`, то нужно указать тип соответствующий этому полю, в данном случае `str`. Но у вас возвращается не name, а объект целиком.

Comment: @insolor, в object_ прилетит перечисление, в зависимости от figure. Для примера: если figure == "Прямоугольник", тогда в object_ будет FigureNames.rectangle. Как мне это отразить в аннотации?

Comment: Так и указывайте `"FigureNames"`. `FigureNames.rectangle` будет относиться к классу `FigureNames`. См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52624736/4752653

Comment: @insolor , простите пожалуйста, я пытаюсь разобраться. Я ведь правильно понимаю, что FigureNames.rectangle - это атрибут класса? 2-й вопрос, в аннотации нельзя конкретно указать, что возвращает именно атрибут класса? Без использования typing.Optional[] и перечисления всех элементов?

Comment: В аннотации указывается **тип** значения, а не его суть. Если это значение аттрибута, то значит тип значения аттрибута. Это **type** hints, а значит только тип. Вызывающему коду важно только знание типа, чтобы правильно работать с полученным результатом, а не откуда оно взялось. `FigureNames.rectangle` - это часть enum, что не совсем обычный класс

Comment: `Я ведь правильно понимаю, что FigureNames.rectangle - это атрибут класса?` - для `Enum` это не просто атрибут класса, а экземпляр данного класса-перечисления (`FigureNames`). Соответственно, в аннотации и нужно указать этот класс. Технически, это конечно атрибут класса, но для Enum такой атрибут хранит ссылку на конкретный экземпляр этого класса, т.е. `type(FigureNames.rectangle) is FigureNames`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас и так верно указан тип возвращаемого значения:

```
@classmethod
def keyForValue(cls, figure: str) -> "FigureNames":
```

Каждый атрибут в enum имеет тип класса, в котором он объявлен (т.е. например `type(FigureNames.rectangle) is FigureNames`), поэтому нужно просто указать этот класс.